# How to make arch shape?

Tags: modeling, boolean-modifier

How do I make this arch shape?

[image: Arch shape]

I have tried all the boolean object shapes but it is impossible.

In uploaded Blender file, tpoop mesh is my last try.
[image]

[image: (My last try)]

Comment: wow if you do everything with boolean it won't make things easy  ^^

Comment: your tpoop looks like this:  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/adMYt.png ---> red means: wrong face orientation and this "normally" means: big problems with boolean modifiers